# cmake if condition inside macro /function

Tags: cmake

I am using

It is always going inside else function why ?

```
function(add_exe_name exe STAND2)
if(STAND2 EQUAL FALSE)
MESSAGE (FATAL_ERROR "Are bhi ${STAND} ${STAND2}")
SET(${exe}-exe "app-${exe}")
SET(${exe}-temp "app-${exe}")
else()
MESSAGE (FATAL_ERROR "${STAND} ${STAND2}")
SET(${exe}-exe "app-${exe}")
SET(${exe}-temp "${exe}")
endif(STAND2 EQUAL FALSE)
endfunction(add_exe_name)
```

It is not taking care about value of STAND2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `if(STAND2 EQUAL FALSE)` with `if(NOT STAND2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the official explanation about **if** command regarding EQUAL, which requires both handside should be **a valid number**, this is the reason why your if branch never gets evaluated.

```
  if(<variable|string> LESS <variable|string>)
  if(<variable|string> GREATER <variable|string>)
  if(<variable|string> EQUAL <variable|string>)
```

```
True if the given string or variable's value is a valid number and the inequality or equality is true.
```